# How does the Doctrine Repository mechanism of lazy loading entities work?

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

So, I want to understand how the Doctrine Repository mechanism works.

For my entities I use annotations, so the resulting object is built somewhere during the execution of the script.

I'd like to unserstand which are the possibile ways of implementing the lazy loading of entities from another entity.

In concrete, using Doctrine, I have the ability to [fetch information of related object (from the Symfony book)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-related-objects). This fetching is done in a lazy way: only if I call the method to get the information about the Entity it is loaded from the database querying it.

Now, I'd like to better understand this mechanism: **how an entity can implement repository methods?**
How can I reproduce this mechanism to implement it in other context similar to the one of a database data retrieval?

**As the resulting object is really big, is there someone who can put me on the right way?
Which classes should have I read to understand the mechanism?
Are there any articles/posts that better explain how this mechanism is implemented?
Are there better (or simply simpler) ways of implementing it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best description of the lazy loading can be found in Doctrine developer articles.
http://www.giorgiosironi.com/2009/07/lazy-loading-of-objects-from-database.html
http://www.giorgiosironi.com/2009/08/doctrine-2-now-has-lazy-loading.html

The main idea is to insert into Product's category list a set of objectes that are subclasses of Category. These and called "proxy objects" and created "on the fly" when Product is retrieved from database. These proxy objects have the same interface as Category object, but add functionality of loading actual Category items from database when needed.

Comment: the question was how lazy loading entities work but your answer is looks like explaining some another topic

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine actually creates a extra object (think proxy) that keeps a record of what properties have actually been accessed.

See this part from the documentation :

### 32.4.2. Association proxies

The second most important situation where Doctrine uses proxy objects is when querying for objects. Whenever you query for an object that has a single-valued association to another object that is configured LAZY, without joining that association in the same query, Doctrine puts proxy objects in place where normally the associated object would be. Just like other proxies it will transparently initialize itself on first access.

[doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom repository for an entity: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Once you have your own custom repository class you can create queries that fetch all of the information you need in one query rather than relying on lazy loading.

So say you have an Product entity which has one or more Category entities using a ManyToMany relationship you could create a function in your custom repository to fetch all products with their categories in one query:

```
   public function fetchProductsWithCategories()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT p, c FROM Product p join p.categories c'
            )
            ->getResult();
    }
```

Then in your controller you would have something like:

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('Product');
$products = $repo->fetchProductsWithCategories();
```

Edit: missed c in select

Comment: Thank you for your reply dk80, but I'd like to know technically the mechanism how was implemented. I'm not going to use Doctrine, but to implementing the same principles in another library that I'm writing and it's not about databases but about data. I'd like to understand the classes hierarchy and the concepts behind them to be able to use the same approach into my script.